# GitLab pipeline pass along variable to build arg

Tags: docker, ssh, gitlab, dockerfile

Somehow I cannot figure out how to pass along this ssh key to the build process of a container. This is the step in the `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
php:
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:20.10.12-dind
  image: docker:20.10.12
  script:
    # Leverage --cache-from and try to use an existing image if it exists
    - echo "$DOCKER_ACCESS_KEY" | docker login --username $DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER --password-stdin
    - docker login registry.gitlab.com -u ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} -p ${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}
    - docker pull $PHP_CACHE_TAG || true
    - cat "$LARAVEL_ENV_FILE" > "$(pwd)/.env"
    - DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --cache-from $PHP_CACHE_TAG
      --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1
      --build-arg SSH_PRIV_KEY="${SSH_PRIV_KEY}"
      --tag $PHP_CACHE_TAG
      --tag $PHP_TAG
      --target=api_prod .
    - docker push $PHP_TAG
    - docker push $PHP_CACHE_TAG
```

It's about this line: `--build-arg SSH_PRIV_KEY="${SSH_PRIV_KEY}"`

In the Dockerfile I do this: `echo "$SSH_PRIV_KEY" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa; \` (After defining `ARG SSH_PRIV_KEY` at the top of the Dockerfile)

The `/root/.ssh/id_rsa` remains empty afterwards.

For more context of what I do in the Dockerfile:

```
# Needed to be able to install custom dependencies
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh; \
    ssh-keyscan -H gitlab.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts; \
    echo "$SSH_PRIV_KEY" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa; \
    cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa; \
    chmod 600 /root/.ssh/*;
```

I suspect I'm doing something wrong in the gitlab-ci build step. But not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Docker file, use
`ARG SSH_PRIV_KEY`

then you use

```
ARG SSH_PRIV_KEY
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh; \
    ssh-keyscan -H gitlab.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts; \
    echo "$SSH_PRIV_KEY" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa; \
    cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa; \
    chmod 600 /root/.ssh/*;
```

This should work.

Comment: Hello Prahbu, I'm not sure if you read that I defined it? I have it defined at the top of my Dockerfile already.

Comment: AHA! Alright. I am using a multi stage build, and the ARG cannot be defined outside the build stage. So to have this arg work in the correct stage `FROM php:${PHP_VERSION}-fpm-alpine AS api_base`, it has to be defined in the stage.